# Trendline On Google Line Chart

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I am trying to figure out how to add a trendline to my google line chart but am failing miserably. Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? I have seen that google do not provide a way to do this on a line chart but have also seen that it is possible to add a new series into the chart to achieve something similar. Here is what I have so far which works great besides not having a trendline. I have tried a few suggestions I found online but none of them made the maths clear to get the trendline to be a straight line:

```
function drawChartCustomerRevenue_93() {
    var revenueChart_93;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', Date);
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales Value');
    data.addRow(['Apr 2013', 271176.940000000]);
    data.addRow(['May 2013', 419031.540000000]);
    data.addRow(['Jun 2013', 429155.540000000]);
    data.addRow(['Jul 2013', 443780.400000000]);
    data.addRow(['Aug 2013', 320353.540000000]);
    data.addRow(['Sep 2013', 310640.910000000]);
    data.addRow(['Oct 2013', 252187.700000000]);
    data.addRow(['Nov 2013', 301414.560000000]);
    data.addRow(['Dec 2013', 224296.850000000]);
    data.addRow(['Jan 2014', 291131.140000000]);
    data.addRow(['Feb 2014', 354750.680000000]);
    data.addRow(['Mar 2014', 312736.710000000]);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        fractionDigits: 2,
        prefix: '£'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    var chartHeight = 400;
    var chartWidth = 500;
    var chartOptions = {
        trendlines: {
            {
                color: 'green',
            }
        },
        title: '1: TEST NAME',
        isStacked: true,
        width: chartWidth,
        height: chartHeight,
        colors: ['#0000D4'],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Sales Value (£)',
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 45,
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 10
            },
        },
        chartArea: {
            left: 100,
            top: 20,
            width: (chartWidth - 10),
            height: (chartHeight - 90)
        }
    };
    revenueChart_93 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('CustomerRevenue_93'));
    revenueChart_93.draw(data, chartOptions);
};
drawChartCustomerRevenue_93();
```

EDIT:

I have now attempted to put the code in suggested to me but it still shows no trendline:

```
function drawChartCustomerRevenue_93() {
    var revenueChart_93;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales Value');
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 4, 1), 184656.440000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 5, 1), 420286.250000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 6, 1), 431562.840000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 7, 1), 446187.800000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 8, 1), 320353.540000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 9, 1), 313364.960000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 10, 1), 252187.700000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 11, 1), 303874.560000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 12, 1), 224296.850000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 1, 1), 297499.970000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 2, 1), 354950.680000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 3, 1), 315529.610000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 4, 1), 145219.710000000]);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        fractionDigits: 2,
        prefix: '£'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
    });
    dateFormatter.format(data, 0);
    var chartHeight = 320;
    var chartWidth = 400;
    var chartOptions = {
        trendlines: {
            0: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        title: '1: Test Name',
        isStacked: true,
        width: chartWidth,
        height: chartHeight,
        colors: ['#0000D4'],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Sales Value (£)',
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 45,
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 10
            },
            format: 'MMM yyyy',
        },
        chartArea: {
            left: 100,
            top: 20,
            width: (chartWidth - 8),
            height: (chartHeight - 72)
        }
    };
    revenueChart_93 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('CustomerRevenue_93'));
    revenueChart_93.draw(data, chartOptions);
};
drawChartCustomerRevenue_93();
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google charts trendline not showing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642276/google-charts-trendline-not-showing)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, as @mcgyver5 pointed out, trendlines are not supported for discrete (string-based) axes.  Since your data is monthly, you can switch to a Date axis instead of a string axis, which would fix that issue.  Also, your `trendlines` option is not specified correctly.

Here's an example that fixes both issues:

```
function drawChartCustomerRevenue_93() {
    var revenueChart_93;
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Sales Value');
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 3, 1), 271176.940000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 4, 1), 419031.540000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 5, 1), 429155.540000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 6, 1), 443780.400000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 7, 1), 320353.540000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 8, 1), 310640.910000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 9, 1), 252187.700000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 10, 1), 301414.560000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2013, 11, 1), 224296.850000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 0, 1), 291131.140000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 1, 1), 354750.680000000]);
    data.addRow([new Date(2014, 2, 1), 312736.710000000]);
    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        fractionDigits: 2,
        prefix: '£'
    });
    formatter.format(data, 1);
    var dateFormatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({
        pattern: 'MMM yyyy'
    });
    dateFormatter.format(data, 0);
    var chartHeight = 400;
    var chartWidth = 500;
    var chartOptions = {
        trendlines: {
            0: {
                color: 'green'
            }
        },
        title: '1: TEST NAME',
        isStacked: true,
        width: chartWidth,
        height: chartHeight,
        colors: ['#0000D4'],
        hAxis: {
            title: 'Sales Value (£)',
            slantedText: true,
            slantedTextAngle: 45,
            textStyle: {
                fontSize: 10
            },
            format: 'MMM yyyy'
        },
        chartArea: {
            left: 100,
            top: 20,
            width: (chartWidth - 10),
            height: (chartHeight - 90)
        }
    };
    revenueChart_93 = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('CustomerRevenue_93'));
    revenueChart_93.draw(data, chartOptions);
}
```

see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/j8N48/

Comment: I implemented your example word for word however I still do not get the trendline. I noticed I am not getting the error: /Common/JavaScripts/GoogleChartApi/static/modules/gviz/1.0/orgchart/orgchart.css 404 (Not Found). I had a look and I am indeed missing this css class. I cannot seem to find where I can download this from . Do you have any suggestions as to where I could find it?

Comment: If you followed my code example, you should have a trendline.  Update your question with the code you are now using and I'll take a look.  As for the missing file, are you using an OrgChart somewhere?  If not, you don't need that CSS file.

Comment: I have added the code you showed to my page but it still shows no trendlines. I was getting an error about a missing css file called orgchart.css.

Comment: I see in your code you are calling `drawChartCustomerRevenue_93` directly instead of using the callback from the google loader, as in the jsfiddle example.  You need to wait for the API to load before you can use any components.  Change your code to draw in the callback from the google loader, like this: `google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['corechart'], callback: drawChartCustomerRevenue_93});`.

Answer (score 2):

check it out:  [Google charts trendline not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19642276/google-charts-trendline-not-showing?rq=1)

that says your first column cannot be a string because it is not a continuous domain axis.